# How to come up with a flat count output in DocumentDB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to come up with a simple, flat output for document counts in DocumentDB.  For example if I have the following three documents:

```
    { 
      "id": "1", 
      "statusId": "new", 
    }
    { 
      "id": "2", 
      "statusId": "new", 
    }
    { 
      "id": "3", 
      "statusId": "complete", 
    }
```

and if I run this in the Azure Query Explorer:

```
    select Value Count(1) from c
    where c.statusId = "new"
```

I get this:

```
[
  2
]
```

What I am trying to figure out how to do is produce a result that looks *something* like this:

```
{
    "new": 2,
    "complete" : 1
}
```

Even if that's not possible it would be okay to just run multiple selects in the same window at once. However when I try that I get syntax errors in the Query Explorer, i.e.

```
select Value Count(1) from c
where c.statusId = "new"

select Value Count(1) from c
where c.statusId = "complete"
```

produces

```
Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'select'.
```

Comment: Any updates now?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, you want to implement function like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXX GROUP BY XXX` in azure cosmosdb queries.

Per my experience, `azure cosmosdb aggregation` capability in SQL limited to `COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG` functions. `GROUP BY` or other aggregation functionality are not be supported in [azure cosmosdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates) now.

However, `stored procedures` or `UDF` can be used to implement your aggregation requirement.

You could refer to a great package [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) based on DocumentDb stored procedure.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, I don't have an easy answer for you. You can construct the desired JSON after getting the result back.

and second, today you can not execute two select statement in query window.